Can one expect an implicit solution of a system of two equations in two variables?
Given two regular functions $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$, consider the following system:
\begin{align} &f(x,y)=0 \\
& g(x,y)=0 \end{align}
over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}_p} \times \bar{\mathbb{Q}_p}$, where $\bar{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ denotes the algebraic closure of the $p$-adic number field $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Note that $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ both can be a series, in my assumption. Also assume that the determinant of Jacobian matrix
$$J(f,g)=\begin{bmatrix} f_x & f_y \\ g_x & g_y \end{bmatrix} $$ is non-zero.
Suppose I know the above system has finitely many solutions.
Is it theoritically possible to write anyone of $x$ and $y$ in terms of the other?
That is, is it possible to express $x=u(y)$ or $y=v(x)$ for some regular functions $u$ and $v$?

Suppose $(x_i,y_i),~i=1,2, \cdots, n$ be $n$-solutions (simultaneous) of the system. Since the determinant of the Jacobian matrix is non-zero, we can apply the implicit function theorem locally at each solution $(x_i,y_i)$ and so we may write $x$ as piecewise functions:
$$ x=\left\{\begin{aligned} x_1(y) ~\text{for}~y \in O_1 \\
x_2(y)~\text{for}~y \in O_2 \\
\cdots \\
x_n(y) ~\text{for}~y \in O_n\end{aligned} \right. $$
for some open subsets $O_i$ of $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_p$.
I am looking for a regular function $u$ such that $x=u(y)$.

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
A regular function $\ u\ $ satisfying $\ u\big(y_i\big)=x_i\ $ exists if and only if your set of solutions doesn't include two, $\ \big(x_{i_1},y_{i_1}\big),\big(x_{i_2},y_{i_2}\big)\ ,$ with $\ y_{i_1}=y_{i_2}\ $ but $\ x_{i_1}\ne x_{i_2}\ .$ If this condition isn't satisfied then $\ u\ $ obviously could not exist because if $\ u\big(y_{i_1}\big)=x_{i_1}\ $ then $\ u\big(y_{i_2}\big)=u\big(y_{i_1}\big)=x_{i_1}$$\,\ne x_{i_2}\ $ and if $\ u\big(y_{i_2}\big)=x_{i_2}\ $ then $\ u\big(y_{i_1}\big)=u\big(y_{i_2}\big)=x_{i_2}\ne x_{i_1}\ .$
If the condition is satisfied, however, then after any duplicate occurrences of the same solution have been removed,$\left.\right.^\color{red}{\dagger}$ then the Lagrange interpolation polynomial,
$$
u(y)\ed\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\prod_{j=1\\j\ne i}^n\left(\frac{y-y_j}{y_i-y_j}\right)\ .
$$
is a regular function with $\ u\big(y_i\big)=x_i\ $ for $\ i=1,2,\dots,n\ ,$ regardless of any properties of the Jacobian matrix.
Likewise, if $\ x_i\ne x_j\ $ for $\ i\ne j\ ,$ and
$$
v(x)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\sum_{i=1}^ny_i\prod_{j=1\\j\ne i}^n\left(\frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}\right)\ .
$$
then $\ v\ $ is a regular function satisfying $\ v\big(x_i\big)=y_i\ $ for $\ i=1,2,\dots,n\ .$
You appear to have misapplied the implicit function theorem, which requires the dimension of the domain of the function to which it's being applied to exceed the dimension of its codomain. But the domain and codomain your function $\ (f,g):\bar{\mathbb{Q}_p}^2\rightarrow\bar{\mathbb{Q}_p}^2\ $ are the same—namely $\ \bar{\mathbb{Q}_p}^2\ $—and both have the same dimension, $2$. Possibly, you're confusing it with the inverse function theorem, which tells you that if the Jacobian $\ J(f,g)\big(x_i,y_i)\ $ is non-singular, then there exists a function $\ h:O\rightarrow\bar{\mathbb{Q}_p}^2\ ,$ defined on a neighbourhood $\ O\ $ of $\ (0,0)\ $ in $\ \bar{\mathbb{Q}_p}^2\ $ such that
$$
h(0,0)=\big(x_i,y_i)
$$
and
\begin{align}
f(h(w,z))&=w\\
g(h(w,z))&=z
\end{align}
for $\ (w,z)\in O\ .$
I very much doubt that the non-singularity of the Jacobian everywhere is sufficient to guarantee the conditions needed for the functions $\ u\ $ and $\ v\ $ given above to be well defined, but I'm not sufficiently familiar with $p$-adic analysis to attempt the construction of a counterexample.  The mere nonsingularity of the Jacobian at the common zeroes $\ x_i,y_i\ $ of the functions $\ f,g\ $ is certainly not sufficient, however, as shown by the following counterexample
If
\begin{align}
f(x,y)\ed x^2+y^2-5\\
g(x,y)\ed x^2-y^2-3\ ,
\end{align}
then the Jacobian
$$
\pmatrix{f_x(x,y)&f_y(x,y)\\g_x(x,y)&g_y(x,y)}=\pmatrix{2x&2y\\2x&-2y}
$$
is singular if and only if at least one of $\ x\ $ or $\ y\ $ is zero.
In $\ \bar{\mathbb{Q}_p}^2\ ,$ however, the equations
\begin{align}
x^2+y^2-5&=0\\
x^2-y^2-3&=0\\
\end{align}
have four solutions
\begin{align}
x_1&=2,y_1=1\\
x_2&=2,y_2=-1=\sum_{i=0}^\infty(p-1)p^n\\
x_3&=-2=p-2+\sum_\limits{i=1}^\infty(p-1)p^n,y_3=1\ \ \text{and}\\
x_4&=-2, y_4=-1\ ,
\end{align}
and neither of the conditions needed for the functions $\ u\ $ or $\ v\ $ given above to exist are satisfied.
$\left.\right.^\color{red}{\dagger}$ So that $\ y_i\ne y_j\ $ for $\ i\ne j\ .$

i think the condition, you mentioned, is satisfied in this case, because I know the solutions are distinct. So if $(x,y) \neq (x', y')$, and if $x=x'$, we must have $y\neq y'$.

No. If $\ x=x'\ $ and $\ y\ne y'\ $ that is precisely when the condition for $\ v\ $ to exist is not satisfied.  It may still be the case, however, that the condition for $\  u\ $ to exist is satisfied.  That depends on whether there exist solutions $\ (x,y)\ $ and $\  (x',y)\  $ with $\ x'\ne x\ .$

sorry for misunderstanding your condition. All you want to exists $u$ if  none of $y$-coordinates are equal because in that case the denominator vanishes and same for the other case $v$. But if i have the opportunity to assume that none of the $x$-coordinates are equal, then we can apply Lagrange to get a $v(x)$ in your definition. Am I right?

Yes, if all of the $\ x_i$s are distinct then $\ v\ $ is well-defined and if all the $\ y_i$s are distinct then $\ u\ $ is well-defined.

thanks. Also thanks for revisiting the implicit function thm and inverse function thm which I forgot long ago.
